# Why do I get null when accessing firstElementChild here?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I am following a tutorial where I have the following HTML

```
<template id="project-input">
  <form>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="people">People</label>
      <input type="number" id="people" step="1" min="0" max="10" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">ADD PROJECT</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

I want to take the `form` in this template and render it inside:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

In my code I have the following class:

```
class ProjectInput {
    templateElm: HTMLTemplateElement;
    appElm: HTMLDivElement;
    element: HTMLFormElement;

    constructor() {
        //I start by getting a reference to the template
        this.templateElm = document.getElementById('project-input') as HTMLTemplateElement;

        //And a reference to the div
        this.appElm = document.getElementById('app') as HTMLDivElement;

        //I import the contents of the template
        const importedNode = document.importNode(this.templateElm, true);

        //And access the form which is the first child
        //This assignment becomes null for some reason
        this.element = importedNode.firstElementChild as HTMLFormElement;

        //I call the attach method which should render the form inside the div
        //This of course results in an error since this.element is null
        this.attach();
    }

    attach() {
        this.appElm.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', this.element);
    }
}

const p = new ProjectInput();
```

For some reason the assignment of `this.element = importedNode.firstElementChild as HTMLFormElement;` becomes `null`.

Can anyone figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you need to use another function istead of `importNode()`. I am not able to post comments, so here is my answer.

1. Please, check if `importedNode` is null.
2. Keep stuff much simpler: you only need to `insertAdjacentElement`, because [the official MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)

> The imported node is not yet included in the document tree. To include it, you need to call an insertion method such as appendChild() or insertBefore() with a node that is currently in the document tree.

3. I suppose that `firstElementChild` is not working with Nodes, that are not appened. Maybe try `importedNode.querySelector('form')` instead of getting first element.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue here is because you put the form in a template and it's not an HTMLElement, it's actually an HTMLTemplateElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement

And there for you need the inside **content** (the final form html element), and insert it to document with **append** or **prepend**

So I would suggest to change little bit the code to

```
class ProjectInput {
    constructor() {
        this.templateElm = document.getElementById('project-input');

        this.appElm = document.getElementById('app');

        const importedNode = document.importNode(this.templateElm, true);

        this.element = importedNode.content;

        this.attach();
    }

    attach() {
        this.appElm.prepend(this.element);
    }
}
```